# Table structure for traversing through css rules

Tags: python, css, parsing, yacc

Im trying to create a www-page renderer on python and a big part of this is CSS parsing and matching against elements.

I've [already created CSS parser](https://github.com/dyatlov/Pyfox) using `ply`. It supports css2.1 syntax and partially css3.

Now I want to create some structure for easy style extracting for given element.
Example:

css:

```
a { display: block; font-size: 12pt; }
div p.links a { color: green; display: inline; }
```

Lets assume that I parsed it and that needed structure is created.

Then it should be easy to query that structure with such things:

`cssTable.get_styles( 'html > div#content > h3 > a' );`

It would return first ruleset: `{ display: block; font-size: 12pt; }`

If I query it with this:

`cssTable.get_styles( 'html > div#content > p.links > a' );`

It would return merged ruleset: `{display: inline; color: green; font-size: 12pt;}`

So guys, do you have anything that you can suggest me to use as such structure?

Comment: I'd be considering a gigantic structure that holds all the possible style properties. Then when initialising, set all of them to `auto` or 'inherit'.

Comment: yes, all possible properties is a must-have. Just looking for a fast way to get needed rules to merge. At the moment Im looking for reverse selector table (css) and reverse path (html) as a filter, so that I could quickly traverse trough css and remove incorrect pathes and then merge the rest. Maybe someone has better idea.